# vectorizing Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, auto-vectorization

This is a data-cleaning exercise where specific elements of a dataframe A ought to be set to NaN depending on values that are decoded through B.

I have written the following code in which the 3-nested loops would run for 17h:

```
def Convert(input):
    X = np.fromstring(input[1:-1], dtype=np.int, sep=',')
    return X
tf = B
# B is a dataframe of descriptors for the A dataframe
# the column 'missing_or_unknown' in B is used to determine the elements of A to be replaced
tf['missing_or_unknown'] = B['missing_or_unknown'].apply(lambda x: Convert(x))
Y = tf['missing_or_unknown'].values
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    for j in range(0,85):
        for k in range (0,len(Y[j])):
            if A.iloc[i,j] == Y[j][k]:
                A[i,j] = np.nan
```

I suspect the bottleneck is the long outer loop since `len(A)` is ~ 1 million. So, this is not the best way to use Pandas, and I would instead go for:

```
for j in range(0,85):
      for k in range (0,len(Y[j])):
        if A.iloc[:,j] == Y[j][k]:
                A.iloc[:,j] = np.nan
```

The latter however throws an exception:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

2 Questions:

1. Am I right about the performance bottleneck & benefit from vectorization
2. how to express the if condition in a correct way
3. The calculation of Y is not expensive, it is a look up array to determine how to manipulate the A dataframe

Comment: Yes, looping through a DataFrame is almost never necessary, and having 3 nested loops is surely not needed. What are you trying to accomplish, just looking at a nested loop out of context is very difficult to understand....

Comment: I added more detail to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to substitute with `np.nan` any entry of A equal to the entry of Y in the same position you can use:

```
A[A==Y]=np.nan
```

Does this solve your problem?

Your first code works but it's very slow.

Your second code doesn't work because the if statement is comparing the whole column (*Series*) `A.iloc[:,j]`to a value, which you can do with `.any()`, as suggested.

Here I compare the speed of my code wrt your first try on two dataframe with dimension 100x85:

```
import time
A = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([100,85]))
A.iloc[0,1] = 1
Y = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([100,85]))
start_time = time.time()
A[A==Y]=np.nan
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
--- 0.030421018600463867 seconds ---

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(0,len(A)):
for j in range(0,85):
    for k in range (0,len(Y[j])):
        if A.iloc[i,j] == Y[j][k]:
            A[i,j] = np.nan
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
--- 17.413578748703003 seconds ---
```

Comment: I did a quick test on the solution proposed above; it seems to be OK and it only took 20 min. Awesome. I was not aware of these possibilities with Pandas